# How youtube load image

Tags: youtube

I look Youtube load 1 part of images when page load, when i scroll down , it'll load continue remain part . What exactly youtube use, it load remain part image very fast.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you describe in more detail what you see, and the behavior you want implement?

Answer (score 3):

I can't quite understand if this is what you're looking for: [LazyLoad for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)
It's not what YouTube uses, but it should work similarly.